# Not able to highlight a number of words in a text on python

Tags: python, tkinter

I was wondering what is wrong here? It should be highlighting all the words in a list when a button is clicked. However, this is the error that comes up:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback <br>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Reuben_2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Reuben_2/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Writing is hard/MyHighlighter.py", line 54, in highlight_text
    pos = ArticleTextBox.search(names[2], pos, stopindex=END, count=lenght)
  File "C:\Users\Reuben_2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3332, in search
    return str(self.tk.call(tuple(args)))
_tkinter.TclError: bad text index ""
```

Here is my code:

```
  def highlight_text():
        article=ArticleTextBox.get(0.0,tk.END)
        my_sent=article
        names=(get_continuous_chunks(my_sent))
        lenght = StringVar()
        pos = '1.0'
        for w in range(0,nameslistlength):
            while True:
                pos = ArticleTextBox.search(names[w], pos, stopindex=END, count=lenght)
                if not pos:
                    break
                ArticleTextBox.tag_add('highlight', pos, '{}+{}c'.format(pos, lenght.get()))
                pos += '+1c'
```

Thank you for your help. Please let me know if you have any questions + any tips on how to improve my stack overflow questions.

Comment: Could it be that names[2] is an empty string? And what is `END` ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Though, you should be able to debug this yourself. I don't see any signs that you've tried. Perhaps you should add some debugging statements, such as printing out the value of `pos` to see if it's what you think it is (clearly, it's not).

Answer (score 0):

The error comes at the start of the second iteration of the `for` loop.

The first iteration can only end when the `while` loop ends, and it can only end when `pos` is the empty string. Thus, when the second iteration of the `for` loop starts, `pos` is the empty string which you then try to use when calling `search`.

The solution is to reset `pos` to `"1.0"` at the start of the `for` loop, assuming that the purpose of the `for` loop is to search then entire widget for each word or phrase in `names`.

By the way, the pythonic way to iterate over a loop isn't to get the length and then iterate over the indexes. Instead, directly iterate over the list:

```
for name in names:
    pos = "1.0"
    while True:
        pos = ArticleTextBox.search(name, ...)
        ...
    ...
```